# sibling with different parents

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm confused.If I want to have a function `move()` for two siblings from different parents(two seperate Div in level 1 in DOM Tree), should I mention the exact parent for moving one node and insert it before another one?
I could find sth like:

```
childNode[6].parentNode.insertBefore(childNode[6],childNode[9]);
```

I don't know how to put index for a node! sorry for silly questions, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the parent of reference node element(which is the second argument) since you are trying to insert the element within that parent.

```
childNode[9].parentNode.insertBefore(childNode[6], childNode[9]);
//-------^^^----
```

Comment: oh.By using id?